# Postgres : Indexing switches to Parallel Seq Scan from index scan when queried for date range exceeding 150 days

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, optimization, index-tuning

I have two tables - exam_data and series_data, with 300M and 900M records each. I have a query which joins the two tables. If I pull the records for the last 90 days, then the query returns within a second. But the moment it exceeds certain date range such as 180 days, then query takes huge amount of time, in excess of 200 seconds, sometimes even 10 minutes.

When I observe the explain plan, one thing that stands out is that, the query switches from index scan to parallel seq scan. Number of workers also increases from 3 to 10. From the infrastructure point of view, the DB is running on AWS RDS server with db.m6g.large instance type, which has 2 vCPUs, 8GB memory.

Below are the query plans - first with the date range set to 180 days and the second one set to 90 days.

### With 180 days

```
Limit  (cost=57228.52..700532.83 rows=1000 width=198)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=57228.52..30312473.74 rows=47031 width=198)
        Join Filter: (exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = reff.mdp_source_connector_ref_id)
        ->  Gather  (cost=57228.52..30171353.12 rows=18445 width=174)
              Workers Planned: 10
              ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=56228.52..30168508.62 rows=1844 width=174)
                    Hash Cond: ((series.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id) AND (series.exam_id = exam.exam_id))
                    ->  Parallel Seq Scan on series_data series  (cost=0.00..29035458.82 rows=107681532 width=75)
                          Filter: (filtered_flag = 'N'::text)
                    ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=56216.33..56216.33 rows=813 width=130)
                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on exam_data exam  (cost=165.66..56216.33 rows=813 width=130)
                                Recheck Cond: (system_id = '60743ABCDC'::text)
                                Filter: ((filtered_flag = 'N'::text) AND (exam_enddatetime_ts >= (CURRENT_DATE - 180)))
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on exam_system_id  (cost=0.00..165.03 rows=14462 width=0)
                                      Index Cond: (system_id = '60743ABCDC'::text)
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.65 rows=510 width=36)
              ->  Seq Scan on mdp_source_connector_ref reff  (cost=0.00..15.10 rows=510 width=36)
```

### With 90 days

```
Limit  (cost=1165.97..686763.18 rows=1000 width=198)
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1165.97..11702939.19 rows=17068 width=198)
        Join Filter: (exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = reff.mdp_source_connector_ref_id)
        ->  Gather  (cost=1165.97..11651721.36 rows=6693 width=174)
              Workers Planned: 3
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=165.97..11650052.06 rows=2159 width=174)
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on exam_data exam  (cost=165.26..56215.92 rows=295 width=130)
                          Recheck Cond: (system_id = '60743ABCDC'::text)
                          Filter: ((filtered_flag = 'N'::text) AND (exam_enddatetime_ts >= (CURRENT_DATE - 90)))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on exam_system_id  (cost=0.00..165.03 rows=14462 width=0)
                                Index Cond: (system_id = '60743ABCDC'::text)
                    ->  Index Scan using series_data_exam_id on series_data series  (cost=0.70..39289.00 rows=1214 width=75)
                          Index Cond: (exam_id = exam.exam_id)
                          Filter: ((filtered_flag = 'N'::text) AND (exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = mdp_source_connector_ref_id))
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.65 rows=510 width=36)
              ->  Seq Scan on mdp_source_connector_ref reff  (cost=0.00..15.10 rows=510 width=36)
```

Below is the query used

```
> SELECT exam.system_id, reff.modality, exam.exam_number,
> exam.exam_duration, exam.exam_startdate,     exam.operator,
> exam.study_type, exam.load_time AS lastupdatedtime, exam.exam_id,
>     exam.exam_startdatetime_ts, exam.exam_enddatetime_ts, exam.referring_physician,
>     exam.contrast_used, series.series_startdatetime_ts, series.series_enddatetime_ts,
>     series.series_number, series.series_modality, series.series_description, series.series_duration    FROM
> device_utilization.exam_data exam
>      JOIN device_utilization.mdp_source_connector_ref reff ON exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = reff.mdp_source_connector_ref_id
>      JOIN device_utilization.series_data series ON exam.exam_id = series.exam_id AND exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id =
> series.mdp_source_connector_ref_id
>      WHERE exam.system_id = '63046ABCDA'  and exam_enddatetime_ts >=current_date -360     and exam.filtered_flag = 'N'::text AND series.filtered_flag = 'N'::text
```

Couple of optimizations planned out are

1. We are including partitioning on the exam_enddatetime_ts column. Not sure if this will have any impact on the type of indexing used.
2. We are looking at increase the instance size from 2 cores to 4 cores.

Looking for the input on why does the index switches from index scan to parallel seq scan. Also any other input how can I optimize the query response time.

Thanks,
Prasanna

**UPDATES on further questions**

**The output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) is included below for the query which pulled 180 days of data.**

```
Limit  (cost=1358.99..784417.12 rows=1000 width=198) (actual time=50.950..194.047 rows=1000 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=5532 read=1576
  I/O Timings: read=677.975
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=1358.99..14066649.07 rows=17962 width=198) (actual time=50.948..193.912 rows=1000 loops=1)
        Join Filter: (exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = reff.mdp_source_connector_ref_id)
        Rows Removed by Join Filter: 7995
        Buffers: shared hit=5532 read=1576
        I/O Timings: read=677.975
        ->  Gather  (cost=1358.99..14012746.10 rows=7044 width=174) (actual time=50.923..191.700 rows=1000 loops=1)
              Workers Planned: 3
              Workers Launched: 3
              Buffers: shared hit=5531 read=1576
              I/O Timings: read=677.975
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=358.99..14011041.70 rows=2272 width=174) (actual time=43.362..182.427 rows=251 loops=4)
                    Buffers: shared hit=5531 read=1576
                    I/O Timings: read=677.975
                    ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on exam_data exam  (cost=165.26..56215.92 rows=286 width=130) (actual time=41.051..149.211 rows=237 loops=4)
                          Recheck Cond: (system_id = '607431D656B'::text)
                          Filter: ((filtered_flag = 'N'::text) AND (exam_enddatetime_ts >= (CURRENT_DATE - 90)))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 3069
                          Heap Blocks: exact=371
                          Buffers: shared hit=102 read=1310
                          I/O Timings: read=571.800
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on exam_system_id  (cost=0.00..165.03 rows=14462 width=0) (actual time=4.123..4.124 rows=13223 loops=1)
                                Index Cond: (system_id = '607431D656B'::text)
                                Buffers: shared read=15
                                I/O Timings: read=3.183
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on series_data series  (cost=193.74..48780.83 rows=1227 width=75) (actual time=0.133..0.138 rows=1 loops=947)
                          Recheck Cond: (exam_id = exam.exam_id)
                          Filter: ((filtered_flag = 'N'::text) AND (exam.mdp_source_connector_ref_id = mdp_source_connector_ref_id))
                          Rows Removed by Filter: 0
                          Heap Blocks: exact=251
                          Buffers: shared hit=5429 read=266
                          I/O Timings: read=106.175
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on series_data_exam_id  (cost=0.00..193.43 rows=12426 width=0) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=947)
                                Index Cond: (exam_id = exam.exam_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=4684 read=54
                                I/O Timings: read=19.526
        ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..17.65 rows=510 width=36) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=9 loops=1000)
              Buffers: shared hit=1
              ->  Seq Scan on mdp_source_connector_ref reff  (cost=0.00..15.10 rows=510 width=36) (actual time=0.012..0.014 rows=9 loops=1)
                    Buffers: shared hit=1
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=344 read=99 dirtied=1
  I/O Timings: read=49.324
Planning Time: 53.288 ms
Execution Time: 194.222 ms
```

Comment: Your query does not have a LIMIT, but your plans do.

Comment: Having a multi column index on `(system_id, exam_enddatetime_ts)` in that order may make a large difference.  As well as having one on `(exam_id, mdp_source_connector_ref_id)`.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL switches to a sequential scan because it thinks that the execution time will be shorter that way. If it isn't, it may be a configuration problem:

- Perhaps you told PostgreSQL that index scans are expensive by leaving `random_page_cost` at its default value 4, which may be appropriate for spinning disks, but not for anything else.
- Perhaps index scans are fast because the index is cached. If you increase `effective_cache_size`, PostgreSQL will know that the index is probably cached and will lower the cost of index scans.
- Perhaps you specified a degree of parallelism that exceeds the capacities of your hardware, so the parallel table scan is slower than PostgreSQL thinks. Consider lowering `max_parallel_workers_per_gather`.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get 10 workers planned is to have max_parallel_workers_per_gather set to at least 10.  But that setting seems entirely nuts for a machine with only 2 vCPU. The best setting for that is probably 0, maybe 1 or 2.  I wonder what other insane settings you might have.

That change alone should get it to switch to a better plan.  It should probably be using a better plan anyway, but exploring that better would be helped by having `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output rather than just `EXPLAIN`.  (Especially if track_io_timing is turned on first)

Comment: Thanks jjanes for your response. I could not understand your suggestion of "That change alone should get ...". Are you suggesting that, I set max_parallel_workers_per_gather to 2?

Comment: I have included the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) in the problem statement itself. I do not know how to interpret the buffers. But here is the first line that might be of interest "Buffers: shared hit=4714568 read=1050672 dirtied=22". How do I interpret this number to be very high? Or is it manageable? In the other query with 90 days of data, which took only 1 second the buffers shared hit count is 5532.